# How do you view/search for labels in Team Foundation Server 2012 web access?

Tags: tfs

How do you view "Labels" (which we use to tag versions), in Team Foundation Server 2012 Web Access? (it is also listed as version 11)

I see changesets under "Source", but there does not appear to be a way to find/view labels. I have confirmed that the labels exist with VS2012 Source Control Explorer. Am I overlooking something, or is this a missing feature?

Comment: I can't seem to find it either, nor can I see it on uservoice as a request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately it is not possible to see labels in web access. You can use visual studio to view labels. Due to the fact that labels are not immutable I usually recommend using branches and you can see the contents of branches in web access.

Comment: Thanks for the bit of advice to point us in a better direction.

Answer (score 1):

I've just added a request for this https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13243245-ability-to-see-labels-in-browser-view-tfs-web-ac - hopefully it will be added (or maybe its there and I just missed it...)

Comment: Not in 2017 :-(

Comment: Looks like the request tracking moved and this is now located at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365544/ability-to-see-labels-in-browser-view-tfs-web-acce.html